# Como cambio el path de MSBuild Tools?

Tags: c#, vscode

Estoy usando la versión 1.75. 1 de Visual Studio Code y he tenido algunos problemas para configurar OmniSharp, la extensión de C# específicamente, pude resolver algunos de esos problemas pero hay uno que no puedo resolver, y es que mi VSCode no encuentra la ubicación de MSBuild Tools, el cual tengo instalado correctamente (versión de 2015) y el comando msbuild funciona, pero como dije antes, mi Visual Studio Code no encuentra la ubicación de MSBuild Tools. Alguna ayuda porfa?

Comment: Abre el JSON de tus ajustes en VS Code (Ctrl + Shift + P -> UserSettings(JSON)), busca el ` "omnisharp.path": ` y ponle un string vacío o agrega `omnisharp.useModernNet`. También puedes intentar abriendo VS Code desde un CMD de Visual Studio.

Comment: @René No funcionó :'v